# One script for multiple buttons in unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using Unity 5. There are 2 Buttons in a Canvas - YesButton & NoButton. I added only one script called "ButtonScript.cs" in both buttons as a component.

I need -

1. While pressing in YesButton, `Debug.Log("Yes");`
2. While pressing in NoButton, `Debug.Log("No");`

What should I write in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many way to do that but i mostly use this one...

```
public void buttonDownEvent(BaseEventData eventData){

    if (eventData.selectedObject == null)
        return;

    string textCheck = eventData.selectedObject.name;

    switch (textCheck) {

     case "Yes":
        Debug.Log(textCheck); // OutPut is YES;
        break;
     case "NO":
        Debug.Log(textCheck); // OutPut is NO;
        break;
     default:
        break;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay kumar.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. First one is taht you can operate on Tags:

```
Debug.Log(gameObject.Tag == "YesButton" ? "Yes" : "No");
```

But (imo) dealing with tags is painfull so the easiest way would be to just make some enumeration (for future improvements like "Yes", "No", "Cancel" etc.)

```
public enum ButtonType : byte {
    YES = 0,
    NO = (1 << 0)
}

// inside your button code
[SerializeField]
ButtonType _myType;
public ButtonType Type { get { return _myType; } }
```

**EDIT:**

Usage with Unity's event

```
// inside ButtonScript.Start() or ButtonScript.Awake()
this/* Button */.onClick.AddListener(new UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction(ButtonClicked));

// and now make a new method inside ButtonScript
void ButtonClicked()
{
    // method with tags:
    Debug.Log(gameObject.Tag == "YesButton" ? : "Yes" : "No");
    // method with enumeration:
    Debug.Log(_myType.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to work with Unity's event system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is have a parameter passed into the method you want to call `OnClick`, so in your `ButtonScript.cs` file - you can have something like this

```
public void ClickLog(string theWord)
{
    Debug.Log(theWord);
}
```

When you attach this method to the `OnClick` of the buttons, you can input what you want to pass into the method through the editor.

In the case that the `Buttons` are being created in code - you can add parameters to `OnClick` events like so

```
//Button called newButton
UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction action1 = () => { ButtonScript.ClickLog("Yes"/*or "No"*/); };
 newButton.onClick.AddListener(action1);
```

Comment: IMO it would be easier to just use generic form of `UnityAction` like `UnityAction<string>`.